# Display IplImage (JavaCV) on an SWT canvas

Tags: java, image, opencv, swt

I'm using JavaCV for a university project. It is essentially a motion detector.

I use the OpenCVFrameGrabber class to get the frames from a webcam and I want to display the grabbed frames on my GUI.

I'm using SWT and I thought it would be good to display the frames into a Canvas component.
I have a problem because the OpenCVFrameGrabber provides images as instances of the IplImage class and SWT uses org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image image class.

So I should convert the image someway from IplImage to SWT Image. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently converted BufferedImages (AWT) to SWT Image Objects.
I made use of the following snippet:  [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/ConvertbetweenSWTImageandAWTBufferedImage.htm)

Maybe the code gets you started. Or someone already converted IplImages to BufferedImages, and you could "pipe" these two conversion methods.

Cheers

Comment: It's easy to convert an awt image to buffered image. IplImage itself exposes a method to do so, I suppose this would wourk. But the team decide to switch back to swing due some other issues with swt and we don't need to convert the images anymore... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

import com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader;
import com.googlecode.javacv.*;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CFrameTest extends JFrame {
    JButton jbtStart;
    JButton jbtStop;
    CanvasFrame frame;
    FrameGrabber grabber;
    IplImage grabbedImage;
    public CFrameTest() {
        super("test");
        setSize(250, 100);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        jbtStart = new JButton("Start camera");
        jbtStop = new JButton("Stop camera");
        this.add(jbtStart);
        this.add(jbtStop);
        setVisible(true);
        jbtStart.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Startcap");
                        jbtStart.setEnabled(false);
                        jbtStop.setEnabled(true);
                        try {

                            (new CameraSwingWorker()).execute();
                            /*startCamera();*/


                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(CFrameTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                });
        jbtStop.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Stopcap");
                        jbtStart.setEnabled(true);
                        jbtStop.setEnabled(false);
                        frame.setVisible(false);
                    }
                });
        Loader.load(opencv_objdetect.class);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CFrameTest testFrame = new CFrameTest();
    }
    public void startCamera() throws Exception {
        frame = new CanvasFrame("Test");
        grabber = new OpenCVFrameGrabber(0);
        CvMemStorage storage = CvMemStorage.create();
        grabber.start();
        grabbedImage = grabber.grab();
        while (frame.isVisible() && (grabbedImage = grabber.grab()) != null)
        {
            BufferedImage bfimg = grabbedImage.getBufferedImage();
            //grabbedImage.copyTo(bfimg);
            frame.showImage(bfimg);

            //frame.showImage(grabbedImage);
            cvClearMemStorage(storage);
        }
        grabber.stop();
    }


    class CameraSwingWorker extends SwingWorker<String, Object> {
        @Override
        public String doInBackground() {
            try {
                startCamera();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "yeah";
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {} catch (Exception ignore) {
            }
        }
    }




}

/*javax.swing.SwingWorker*/
```