# openCV in java - looking to use the split method.

Tags: java, opencv, split, detection

I recently started to work on openCV using java and so far it looks great. I managed to detect faces and play with a threshold. So basically 101 stuff.

Now, I wish to take it one step further, I wish to identify the 'hands' or 'fingers' but for some reason, I noticed that the OpenCV does not contain all methods (functionality) that C++ has. (I may be wrong with this statement)

Given

```
OpenCV cv = new OpenCV();
```

I'm able to do this:

```
cv.absDiff();
```

BUT I'm unable to use other methods such as: split (which exits openCV documentation, http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html#cv-split).

So my question is this: what am I missing here or is the OpenCV for java is limited? 
I haven't used C++ for many years (so I don't really remember the notation).

Thanks for any pointers :-)

Comment: Unable? What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: The method is unavailable, I can't do cv.split(..) // no split method exists in OpenCV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCv is not available in Java as mentioned [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FullOpenCVWiki#Welcome.2FIntroduction.What_is_OpenCV.3F). you should use [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) instead. It contains all the methods in OpenCV.

you can also check the second answer posted on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372785/display-iplimage-javacv-on-an-swt-canvas).

Answer (score 2):

The way I understood it; there're basically two ways to development (as further detailed [here](http://opencv.org/platforms/android/opencv4android-usage-models.html); namely "basic" and "advanced" levels);

1. (advanced level) Using Android NDK which contains all OpenCV's functionalities and has the additional advantage of easier use of ready made C++ code. Also it tends to be faster with larger processing pipelines.
2. (basic level) No need for using Android NDK. This approach utilises OpenCV's API provided for java; a subset (that is perhaps sufficient, application-dependent of course) of OpenCV's functionalities. No NDK (and thus C++) knowledge required.

Both methods could be utilised together, depending on the application's needs.

---

Regarding the `split` method; [here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/) is a link for its documentation in Java. Search for the method name `split`. To call it, use `Core.split(m,chnl);` where `m` is the `Mat` image object and `chnl` is the `List` that holds the resultant separate channels.